New tag: academic?
There was a request to add the tag "academic" with this explanation:

Questions related specifically to the process of Chinese language studying, e.g. in a school or university.

"academic" sounds quite well, uhm, academic to me, while is not necessarily the case for questions related to studying in a school.
Maybe we should add "Learning Chinese" and "Language school" as tags instead?

I agree. Academic (in the context of a Stack that has already distanced itself from the "What does XX mean? How do you say XX?" questions) signifies a higher level discussion of linguistics. If this Stack intends to entertain that type of question, using "academic" to signify the question is arising from a study course or textbook will ultimately be confusing.

I think such a tag would be useful, but not in the originally intended way. For instance, if you require answers with some kind of scholarly/academic backing, this tag could be used to signify that merely stating "I think..." or "According to my own experience...". I'm not sure if there is a demand for a tag like this, because this kind of requirement could be included in the question ("I'm looking for academic articles/books relating to...).

Natural language evolve.  Academic tag really served little purpose. At the end, it will become tl;dr;

Questions about learning or studying Chinese can also be asked on Language Learning SE, where we already have several questions related to Chinese.

This was me who has added an excerpt.
The tag was pretty old; the 1st Q appeared on Dec,23 last year.
In fact, the excerpt just reflected the actual common point of the existing questions.
If you think there's a better content/wording, please don't hesitate to raise a discussion  and/or just edit the tag wiki. There are not that many Q's, so it's easy to re-tag them.

That's weird. I got as request to review this tag this week (I'm new to the reviewing mechanism but I assumed it was a new tag).
